# Hash function without avalanche effect?

Tags: algorithm, function, hash, hashmap, hashtable

According to wikipedia, the avalanche effect is the desirable property of cryptographic algorithms, wherein if an input is changed slightly (for example, flipping a single bit), the output changes significantly (e.g., half the output bits flip).

My question: Is there a hash function that that maps similar inputs to similar hashes (based on a given metric ?)

Comment: I think you're asking for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing but it's a very general question. Do you have a specific problem that you want an answer for?

Comment: @PaulHankin It was exactly what I was looking for. Thanx